# Error in setting std::vector<int> as ros parameter

Tags: c++11, parameters, ros, stdvector, xml-rpc

For my project, I set the ros parameter as follows:

```
    std::vector<int> odomConfig;
    ros::param::param("odom0_config", odomConfig, {false, false, false, false, 
                 false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false});
```

This ros parameter is basically used by `ekf_localization_node` of robot_localization package.

However, an error is thrown from this [line](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/0d3c7cc76461eaee77593c95b390a3a7897e30e2/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2422) of code.

Where am I doing wrong in setting the ros parameter ?

Comment: I don't think this is all the code describing your issue. Could you please try to provide a minimal example to show your issue. This means creation of the param, setting it, getting it, ...

Comment: Issue solved. Just prefixed node name before parameter name.

`std::vector<int> odomConfig;  ros::param::param("ekf_node/odom0_config", odomConfig, {false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false});`